# How to know all the pushed files have been pushed or not in mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I am using mercurial in my Ubuntu 12.04 for version control for some application. I have used these commands to push files 
`hg addremove && hg commit -m 'changes in the comment' && hg push`
It is pushing all the files. But my question is how to know whether all the files have been pushed or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no error, and the push command ends with an output like below:

```
searching for changes
15 changesets found
remote: adding changesets
remote: adding manifests
remote: adding file changes
remote: added 15 changesets with 30 changes to 28 files
[command completed successfully Mon Dec 31 10:32:33 2012]
```

I would safely assume the push is OK.

If you have access to the repository you push to, try `hg heads` and see you have your pushed change sets there.

I hope this gives you a good lead.

Comment: You can also run `hg outgoing`, which answers the question "if I pushed again, what would be pushed?"

Answer (score 2):

`hg help push` clearly states

> Returns 0 if push was successful, 1 if nothing to push.

... other return-codes mean "something was bad". You have to check it and continue operations only in case of zero

Comment: In a scripting environment this is definitely the best answer.